# Can't add image. when I run this process, it's not show. just show a image icon

Tags: html

Can't add image. When I run this process, it's not showing. Just shows an image icon.

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and include a [mcve] in your question, not an image of code

Answer (score 0):

Add the image to your project folder and use relative paths. For example, create an images folder in the root folder and add your image inside of it an try to access it like this : `src="./images/you-image.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Put the image in the same folder as the HTML file, and use the path like this instead of how you have it:

```
<img src="/image.jpg"></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must write like this: `src="../images/example.jpg"`

.. mean 'one folder back'. How many folder back u need, put some ../../../ like this.